# Is there a more idiomatic way to express how many iterations are left in my loop?

Tags: ruby, loops, iteration, idioms

I'm writing a Ruby loop like this:

```
iterations = 10

until iterations == 0
    unless iterations == 1
      puts "#{iterations} iterations until done"
    else
      puts "#{iterations} iteration until done"
    end

    iterations -= 1
end

puts "Done"
```

and I'm wondering if there's a more "Ruby way" to optimize / write this code. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: This question is more suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @GeraldSchneider nice to know about that apparently rather new section!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
10.downto(1) do |iteration|
  puts "#{iteration} iteration#{'s' if iteration > 1} until done"
end
puts 'Done'
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. Of all things I've never included such logic in the string to do that.  EXCELLENT, especially for keeping it sans libs.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'active_support/inflector'

10.downto(1).each { |i| puts "#{i} #{'iteration'.pluralize(i)} until done" }
puts 'Done'
```

Comment: Sorry, but I like Unixmonkey's answer better since it can be done with vanilla Ruby, whereas your solution needs to require Active Support to work. Thanks, though.

Comment: Yes, always love `active_support`, but gotta give props for the pure ruby approach above.

Comment: @GDP2 no need to apologize, just showing an alternative approach.

Comment: Personally, I like using something like ActiveSupport. What happens when the boss wants iteration to change to Octopus? Silly example, but the more I can lean onto others the better. You can just pull in the pluralize method if you wanted.

Comment: @JeffPrice, yes, in a practical use case I can see using ActiveSupport, but I think for the "learning" aspect, the other is also very instructive.  Both are certainly valuable and have real value.  I've also always used the `ActiveSupport` path due to what you say.

Answer (score 0):

### Counting *Up* With a Range Object

If you don't need to count backwards, you can simplify further by iterating a [Range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Range.html) object. For example:

```
(1..10).each { |i| puts "#{i} iterations completed" }
```

This will print:

```
1 iterations completed
2 iterations completed
3 iterations completed
4 iterations completed
5 iterations completed
6 iterations completed
7 iterations completed
8 iterations completed
9 iterations completed
10 iterations completed
```

### Inverting a Range

You could also invert the Range if you already have a Range object and want to count down without having to call [Integer#downto](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Integer.html#method-i-downto). For example:

```
(1..10).to_a.reverse.each  { |i| puts i }
```